# Get attachment name without downloading the whole message

Tags: asp.net, openpop

I do not find a way to get attachment file name without downloading the whole message using OpenPop.Net

The `Pop3Client.GetMessageHeaders` do not expose any data about attachments. The `Pop3Client.GetMessage(messageNumber)` gives attachment data but first download the whole message.

Maybe someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the main developer for OpenPop.Net.
If you take a look at the [RFC for POP3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) you will notice that it is not possible to get information about attachments. To get the message headers, OpenPop.Net current sends the `TOP <messagenumber> 0` command to receive headers.

Since attachment headers are located deep inside the message body, I cannot see how any POP3 client should accomplish your requirement.

IMAP is another protocol, and it includes features which allows the IMAP client to get information about each part inside a message. You might want to go in that direction.